# MySQL table separation for virtually same data but different user groups

Tags: php, mysql, database

First of all, I apologize if a similar question has been asked and answered. I searched and found similar questions, but not one quite close enough.

My question is basically whether or not it is a good idea to separate tables of virtually the same data in my particular circumstance. The tables track data track data for two very different groups (product licensing data for individual users and product licensing data for enterprise users). I am thinking of separating them into two tables so that the user verification process runs faster (especially for individual users since the number of records is significantly lower (eg ~500 individual records vs ~10,000 enterprise records)). Lastly, there is a significant difference in the user types that isn't apparent in the table structure - individual users all have a fixed number of activations while enterprise users may have up to unlimited activations and the purpose of tracking is more for activation stats.

The reason I think separating the tables would be a good idea is because each table would be smaller, resulting in faster queries (at least I think it would...). On the other hand, I will have to do two queries to obtain analytical data. Additionally, I may wish to change the data I am tracking from time to time and obviously, this is more of a pain with two duplicate tables.

I am guessing the query time difference is probably insignificant, even with tens of thousands of records?? However, I would like to hear peoples' thoughts on this (mainly regarding efficiency and overall best practices) if they would be so kind to share.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing your database structure you should try to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data as much as possible. So to answer your question

"whether or not it is a good idea to separate tables of virtually the same data in my particular circumstance."

If you normalize your database correctly, the answer is no, it's not a good idea to create two tables with almost identical information. With normalization you should be able to separate out similar data into mapping tables which will allow you to create more complex queries that will run faster.

A very basic example of a first normal form normalization would be you have a table of users, and in the table you have a column for role. Instead of having the physical word "admin" or "member" you have an id that is mapped to another table called roles where 1 = admin and 2 = member. The idea is it is more efficient to store repeated ids rather then repeated words like admin and member.

Comment: Thank you, Mike, for your response. I appreciate you taking the time. I do understand normalization and try my best to normalize data, however, I am curious as to the reason for your answer "... no, it's not a good idea to create two tables ..." Is this just because it is "bad practice" and redundant? Is there ever a situation that would make this appropriate?

Comment: No problem Paul. Personally, I would say having redundant tables for use other than backups is a bad practice because it can cause confusion in the future. For example let's say the project grows and you have multiple front end and back end developers working together. With redundant tables used for two separate purposes you are introducing risk factors that may not be necessary, which could have drastic consequences later. It is amazing how small things can have big effects on a project once that project scales. So for me it boils down to one more way to keep communication channels clear.

Comment: There is an argument for finding creative ways to optimize your database queries, and having two redundant tables used for separate things definitely falls under the creative problem solving category, however, my response to that is normalization was created to solve the issue you described above. However, once again, never be afraid to break the mold. When it comes to this kind of stuff, there are well proven solutions like normalization, but if people didn't break the mold once in a while we wouldn't have things like nosql. Just make sure the risk is worth the reward.